# API call in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying myself in react and trying to make a simple application, which will display articles from the Hacker News. I have already made the first call to their API

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json?print=pretty')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(articles => {
            this.setState({articles})
        })
  }
```

As the response, it returns an array of the articles IDs. To get detailed information for every single article I need to iterate the array I get and to make a second request for every article ID which has to look like

```
fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/{id_from_the_array}`)
```

And I faced the problem because I have no idea how to implement it in a correct way.. Could someone please advice me?

Comment: Just a `for` loop? Or even better a `foreach` loop

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your errored code? For now on it looks like a typo error in your second `fetch` (`...item/${id...` with a `$`)

Comment: As for now my code looks like

  `constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/askstories.json?print=pretty')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(articles => {
      this.setState({articles})
    })
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help you

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json?print=pretty")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(articles => {
        articles.map(item => {
          fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${item}.json?print=pretty`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(detailArticles => {
              const articles = this.state.articles.concat(detailArticles);
              this.setState({ articles });
              });
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.articles) }</p>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ykrxnox0p9)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is like using pagenation or infinite scroll so you can show some 10 or 15 news on the screen and load the next set of data on click of a button. Else you can show only id's on screen and fetch the data on click of a button.